Hadoop - Final output of the reducer is dependent on values which belong to other keys
To summarize the problem, my input is a list of reviews of bought products together with an associated category.
My goal is to rank the Top n terms of each category according to the chi-square value of each term.
To calculate this, for each term appearing in category, I need to know the frequency this term shows up in other categories as well (amongst other things, but this is the only bit that I can't seem to get around of).
I am using python's mrjob library for the implementation and I have got to a point where at the last step, I have (almost) everything I need as values mapped to a category as key. But I am not sure how I can know the frequency of a term in other categories (a number which is part of values in another key)
I tried using global variables to save these counts and make them available across all jobs, but I soon found out these are not supported by default on hadoop. At least not in Python because I couldn't find anything in mrjob's documentation.
Next solution that comes to mind is writing these counts onto a shared-access file in hdfs but I would like to avoid this if possible.
